# place php errors in log file

Tags: php

I am running mac 10.6.4 on an iMac and am using it as a developer server.

I have Apache and Entropy php5 installed, when i write my applications, some pages wont run when php has errors, however these are not recorded on a log file, I created one php_errors.log and entered the following on the php.ini file

```
error_log = /usr/local/php5/logs/php_errors.log
```

However errors are not written to this file and i have

```
log_errors = true
```

What could be the problem

Answer (score 0):

In your `php.ini` you must also set

```
display_errors = Off
log_errors = true
```

Then restart your webserver.

Comment: I have log_errors = true

Comment: and display_errors?

Answer (score -1):

And if in script exist code like this `error_reporting(0);` than errors wouldn't be written to log file